# Refreshing userdefaults in Swift 4

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, swift4, xcode9

Is it possible to refresh the value of the user defaults in Swift4? The values change after scanning a new product and they are stored in a user default. So when u scan a new product the user default has to refresh.

I hope someone has a solution for me

Comment: Yes you can overwrite values in UserDefaults

Comment: if you reassign a value for a key it will overwrite . UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: key)

Comment: @Scriptable How can i do that? I need to do that when i scanned a product. Then the values have to change

Comment: you just set it again, the same way you set it first time.

Comment: @Scriptable is there something like cache in it? Because sometimes the value changes after i shut the app down and sometimes it won't refresh.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults see the documentation. you set the value and that value remains until you remove it or overwrite it

Comment: Please answer the question apart from comment so that if any body is searching for question he can know a answer is there.

Comment: @RahulDasgupta I didnt give a full answer, thats why I commented instead.

Comment: @Scriptable I am not telling you. I am telling others who are commenting answers.

Answer (score 2):

Set userdefaults as you are setting first time with same key.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: key)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. before setting remove and synchronise it.this might solve your issue

```
func setValueToDefaults(key:String, value:AnyObject){
    self.removeKeyValueFromDefaults(Key:key)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: key)

}

func getValueFromDefaults(key:String) ->AnyObject?{

    if((UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: key)) != nil){

        let value:AnyObject = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: key)! as AnyObject

        return value
    }else{

        return nil
    }

}

func removeKeyValueFromDefaults(Key:String){

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: Key)
    defaults.synchronize()

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround to achieve it, you could declare a computed property for getting/setting the value from the user defaults, example:

```
var flag: Bool {
    get {
        let value = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "flag_key")
        
        return value
    }
    
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "flag_key")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```

reading the value of `flag` returns the Boolean value from the user defaults (of "flag_key" key) and editing its value would be also reflected to the user defaults.